# Checking if platform supports Per-Render Target Blending

Tags: opengl

What would be the best way of checking if platform supports Per-Render Target Blending? In order to implement Weighted Blended Order-Independent
Transparency I need two render targets targets with different blending. On my current platform I am getting black and white in areas where the blending needs to happen. The blending functions are below.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunci(0, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendFunci(1, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: `glBlendFunci` should be supported for all platforms that support OpenGL 4.x, so you can check if you are able to create an OpenGL 4.x context.

Comment: I can create OpenGL 4 context but I tested different demos where I am getting either artefacts or black and white mask.

Comment: @sabotage3d: Then that's either a bug in the driver or a bug in your code. If it's a driver bug, then the driver writers clearly *think* that they support it. So whatever other detection methods you might come up with would also return support for it.

Comment: It is possible as I am under OSX Sierra and the Intel drivers are are very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glBlendFunci` is supported > 4.x. Here is the supported version's excerpt.

[image]

Here is more information about it:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml